# cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

I trying to build a binary using pyinstaller in a Linux environment. I've installed cx_Oracle. When I ran the script it runs fine without any error. However, after building the binary (I use anaconda python package and pyinstaller) when I run the binary it throws me the following error. Could anyone shed some light on this?

I've surfed the issues that discuss py2exe and the same problem, however I couldn't get anything which I can understand as my case is linux and pyinstaller.

Following is the error:

> LOADER: extracted pyi_importers
>   LOADER: Installing import hooks
>   LOADER: out00-PYZ.pyz
>   LOADER: Running scripts
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 41, in 
>   cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
>   LOADER: RC: -1 from pp
>   LOADER: OK.
>   LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.

Comment: The issue was solved after copying connecting ".jar" files from the cx_Oracle bundle to the build directory